How to access fields of inherited objects
I understand how to use inheritance to access methods, but I don't understand how to access fields of a child object when the type of the object is the parent.
(My question is purely about architecture, so the language should not matter, but only FYI, I am using Dart)
I have a parent object and 2 other objects that inherit from it:
class User {
   String id;
   String name;
}

class Person extends User {
   DateTime birthDate;
}

class Company extends User {
   String address;
}

My problem comes when I have to access those fields, specific to the children cases, on an object that is of the parent class. The logged in user of my app is type User, but depending on the type, I will have to display or edit the specific fields.
For example, in the ProfileView, a Person user should display birthdate, and a Company user should display address. The same case is for EditProfile.
This is my solution so far:
User user;

//Initialization and other code

if (user is Person) displayBirthDate();
else if (user is Company) displayAddress();

But this does not use the properties of inheritance.
My question is purely conceptual, independent of the language: How can I access fields of the children classes in an object that is the type of the parent?

Well you're going to have to check which subclass it is before using the fields on the subclass. If you know that the User will only ever be a Person or Company it might be worth declaring User as sealed. Then when you do switch (user) {...} dart will check that you have covered all of the possible subclasses.

Conformation to Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP).
That's what you have done, where LSP states that subtypes must be substitutable for their parent type.
I didn't figure what your problem really is but it revolves around field's access.
Suppose you have a method that accepts an user as a parameter:
    void buildMyWidget(User user){
    
    if(user is Person){
    
    // dart analyzer detects the type, and let you access the Person fields
    }
    else if (user is Company){
    // same access for Company fields
    }
    else{
    //it's the parent
    }
}

You can switch over that object to detect its type.
Moreover, you can even encapsulate that method inside the parent class and override it within the subtypes which frees you from hard type-checking using if-else or switch.
BTW, I was asking a similar question about that point, but was more overlapped with widget building. here
Hope it helps you.

In Dart one could, in principle, refactor the base class User, by making it an abstract generic class. The strategy consists in declaring methods used by all derived classes as abstract methods in the base class and overriding them in the derived class.
abstract class User<T> {
  User({required this.id, required this.name, required this.detail});
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final T detail;
  void displayDetail();
}

class Person extends User<DateTime> {
  Person({required DateTime birthDate, required super.id, required super.name})
      : super(detail: birthDate);

  DateTime get birthDate => detail;

  @override
  displayDetail() {
    print(birthDate);
  }
}

class Company extends User<String> {
  Company({required String address, required super.id, required super.name})
      : super(detail: address);

  String get address => detail;

  @override
  void displayDetail() {
    print(address);
  }
}

